# what and where is the process for on pc windows 10 that is responsible for receiving cast/miracast?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, screencasts, miracast, bitdefender

I would like to cast from android to my pc, which is winodws 10, I have checked the directx diagnosis and my pc supports supports miracast.

I am using bitdefender so i need to allow some processes through the firewall, I just can't figure out where it is.

i have enabled screen sharing setting on private and public network.
I am also able to view to view my laptop name on my phone, which says it is connecting but never connects

Comment: " I have checked the DirectX diagnosis and my pc supports supports miracast." - This check is misleading.  Nvidia and AMD in their current drivers do not actually support Miracast. You must have a display driver and wireless adapter that supports Miracast.  There isn't necessarily a "process" that can be allowed.  If it's not working in all likelihood our hardware does not actually meet the requirements for Miracast. Chromecast is something entirely different and nearly nothing to do with Miracast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PC needs to be able to receive Miracast. The chances may be low,
but here is how to do that:

- Run *Start > Settings > System > Projecting to this PC*
- If you see the following message, then this is impossible:
  "This device doesn't support receiving Miracast, so you can't project
  to it wirelessly."
- If your PC is capable of doing Miracast, continue on
  by following the Microsoft article
  [Screen mirroring and projecting to your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/screen-mirroring-and-projecting-to-your-pc-5af9f371-c704-1c7f-8f0d-fa607551d09c).

Comment: Thank you. I was briefly able to stream wirelessly, and then lost it. But i know now that it is possible. I think my bitdefender is interfering.